# Appregistry error react-native

Tags: react-native

Im starting a react-native project. But even after following best community working code, Im getting errors on device emulation. Could you please help ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Appregistry, Text,View ,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import Compo from './app/app/Compo';

export default class test extends Component {


render(){
  return(
     <View>
       <Compo />
     </View>
  )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
 fontSize: 20,
 textAlign: 'center',
 margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},
});
```

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () =>test);

---

and my called app is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Appregistry,Text,View,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class Compo extends Component {

render(){
  return(
     <View>
       <Text>Hi Bineesh</Text>
     </View>
  )
```

}
   }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Compo', () => Compo);

Why this is throwing error AppRegistry ?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @SagarKhatri can not find variable AppRegistry

Comment: It's a typo in your import statement. `Appregistry = AppRegistry`

Comment: @SagarKhatri pls post your comment as answer.

Comment: first modify your question with proper formating...

Comment: @SagarKhatri , you answer really worked for me. So wanted to upvote. Ie why told to post as answer. Thank you anyways.

Comment: it's ok. Don't waste your time posting this kind of silly questions. Happy coding :)

Comment: @SagarKhatri, I dont think my question was silly bcz i was 100% starter with react-native.

Comment: Than you should first learn es6 and than dive into React-Native. Else you will get lot of fundamental issues which seems silly. And sorry but I didn't mean it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138632/discussion-between-sagar-khatri-and-bineesh).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is caseSensitive and the word Appregistry was to be as AppRegistry.